# Function in if statement: error expected expression

Tags: c++, c, compilation, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I want to compile following file:

https://gist.github.com/bodokaiser/5382281

which does not succeed because I get following error:

```
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/parser/src/parser/parser.o
In file included from ../src/parser/parser.cc:2:
../src/parser/calc_head_size.cc:67:16: error: expected expression
    if (mask || isMasking(masking)) {
               ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/parser/src/parser/parser.o] Error 1
```

This does not make sense to me. Can it be that there is something else wrong?

Bodo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have a strange character in your source code that looks like a space but isn't. In this line:

```
if (mask || isMasking(masking)) {
//         ^ here
```

try to delete the "space" and add a real space.

Comment: @kyogron I don't know, maybe you accidentially pressed a modifier key while pressing space. It depends on your system.

Comment: okay thank you for the answer. good its highlighted in git for the next time